# How can I generate the following pattern using C++?

Tags: c++, for-loop

If  n = 5

```
1   2   1   5
2   4   3   4
3   6   5   3
4   8   7   2
5   10  9   1
```

I have tried the following code but doesn't give the correct output.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j >= i; j++) {
            cout << j;
            j += 2;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Can someone please correct this  code

Comment: `void main()` is not valid in C++

Comment: "but doesn't give the correct output." Please next time provide the output (such that someone willing to help has immediate insight without the need to copy, compile and run the code)

Comment: You've forgot to describe the idea about the output.

Comment: What are requirements on the code? Some `if-else` would surely lead to the desired result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each column of the output follows a pattern, so you can print out the correct values as you iterate through the rows:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
  std::cout << i         << " "   // natural numbers
            << 2 * i     << " "   // even natural numbers
            << 2 * i - 1 << " "   // odd natural numbers
            << n - i + 1 << "\n"; // reversed natural numbers
```